# Error While Uploading File using HttpURLConnection in Java

Tags: java, file-upload, httpurlconnection, multipartform-data

I am using Java HttpURLConnection for uploading a file in which there are two fields, first one is a **key**, which is a plain text and second one is **fileToUpload** a binary file. While uploading these data i am getting **IOException** and response code is **401**. I am putting the right key for authorization but it is not working. here is my code.

```
public FileUpload save() throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
     String responseUrl="";
     final String boundary = "========"+System.currentTimeMillis() + "========";
     final String CRLF = "\r\n";
     HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(serverUrl+"/file/"+appId+"/upload").openConnection();
     connection.setDoOutput(true);
     connection.setDoInput(true);
     connection.setUseCaches(false);
     connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
     connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "CodeJava Agent");
     OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream();
     PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output), true);

     //adding key in header
     writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
     writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"key\"").append(CRLF);
     writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8").append(CRLF);
     writer.append(CRLF);
     writer.append(key).append(CRLF);
     writer.flush();

     //adding file object in header
     writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);            
     writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileToUpload\"; filename=\"" + fileObject.getName() + "\"").append(CRLF);
     writer.append("Content-Type: " + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileObject.getName())).append(CRLF);
     writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(CRLF);
     writer.append(CRLF);
     writer.flush();

     FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileObject);
     byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
     int bytesRead = -1;
     while((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
         output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
     }
     output.flush();
     inputStream.close();
     writer.append(CRLF); // CRLF is important! It indicates end of boundary.
     writer.flush();
     writer.append(CRLF).flush();
     writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(CRLF);
     writer.close();
     //end of http header
     //System.out.println();
     try{   
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
                responseUrl += inputLine;
            in.close();
            this.setUrl(responseUrl);
        }catch (IOException e) {
            this.setUrl(null);
            //System.out.println(e);
        }
     return this;
}
```

as i am new java so i took help from this link http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically

please help me to figure out the bug.

here is the full error trace

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://api.cloudboost.io/file/commentapp/upload
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1627)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at FileUpload.save(CloudFile.java:115)
    at CloudFileTest.saveFiletest(CloudFileTest.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Comment: please copy your exception detail here.

Comment: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://api.cloudboost.io/file/commentapp/upload

Comment: Use the `edit` button and add the information to your question, not in the comments, please. Also, what's required is the full stack trace (several lines), and try to find the line that it says is wrong in your code and mark it for us with a comment.

Comment: it seems the api require some kind of Authentication which you are not providing. And this is not a plain file upload quetion. Update your tage.

Comment: Yes, it needs a key which is a string type. i am providing the key in the above code.